# How to show progress percentage in button

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have a poll's app. layout look like this:
[image: before answered]

After user selected options it must show how every option was mostly selected. I want it to look like this:
[image: after answered]
how to show that percentage proggress in background.
It's not so necessary to use it in buttons view.
I'm not waiting for ready answers, just show me how can I do something like this? what should i use or where to look.

P.S.S. Sorry for my english)

My cardview xml looks like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/poll_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:image="@{poll.pic}"
            tools:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="@string/word_picture" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/poll_id"
                android:text="@{poll.id}"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@{poll.question}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:text="@string/tt_question" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@{poll.desc}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="@string/tt_description" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{poll.option1}"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                tools:text="Вариант 1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/option2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:text="@{poll.option2}"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                tools:text="Вариант 2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_poll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:text="@string/app_next_poll" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried.

Comment: @sidgate I added cardview xml. And want so say that I'm not waiting for ready decision. Just show me is that posible? and what should I use

Answer (score 1):

You could [create your custom view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) that contains both ProgressBar and Button like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Create compound view:

```
class ProgressButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_XML, this)
    }
}
```

And after the button click, you set `progress` to `ProgressBar`, make it visible, and disable button.

```
button.isEnabled = false
with(progress) {
    max = 100
    progress = ... // Your percent value

    // Set your colors to progress bar
    if (correctAnswer) {
        progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(....)
        progressBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(....)
    } else {
        progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(....)
        progressBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(....)
    }
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

And you could use this [compound view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#compound) in your layout later instead of `Button`

Comment: when I show the progress it will not hide the text?

Comment: In this case, I think you could try two solutions: 1) Use transparent drawable for ProgressBar 2) Do not use Button and replace it with ProgressBar with TextView as "button title"

Comment: yes. I did it with Textview above progressbar and got what I need. Thank you for answers.